# How do a gradient path that setting the colors from path begin to end

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to draw a gradient path that **from a color in the begin and end in another color**.

Here are two ways to draw gradient line but the effect neither I want.

Someone has any idea to do this?

```
guard let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    fatalError("Current Context NOT Founds.")
}

c.setLineWidth(width)
c.setLineCap(cap)
c.setLineJoin(join)

// the way no.1
c.saveGState()
c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200))
c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 200))
let alphas: [CGFloat] = [0, 1]
let colors = [UIColor(white: 1, alpha: alphas[0]).cgColor, UIColor(white: 1, alpha: alphas[1]).cgColor] as CFArray
let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors, locations: [0.0, 1.0])
c.addRect(.infinite)
c.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
c.clip()
c.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
c.restoreGState()

// the way no.2
c.saveGState()
c.beginTransparencyLayer(in: rect, auxiliaryInfo: nil)
c.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250))
c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 450))
c.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 130, y: 350))
c.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
c.strokePath()
c.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
c.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 220), end: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 450), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
c.endTransparencyLayer()
c.restoreGState()
```

[image: sample]

---

last update 2017/05/26

Here are some sample images that the effect is similar to I want.

[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

[image: sample3]

Comment: the image you posted is what is the effect you want to get?

Comment: the two effects of the image neither I want .

Comment: Hi ovo, can you post an image that reflects the effect you want?

Comment: @MikeQiu sure, I already updated on my post.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar need, which is basically the same thing but the gradient is perpendicular to what you have here. An example usage would be a gradient curve that renders as a blurred line. This could be done by using a 3 point gradient with 0 alpha on each end. Probably the way it would have to be done is by subdividing the stoke into polygons, each of which would have its own gradient. Lots of work.